# Reload the html to display the info

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

I have a web page in html5 that read an xml and display the info in there. The page is written in jquery.

This is my xml: [xml](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12291198/base_es.xml)

This is my html5: [html](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12291198/hor2.html)

I can read perfectly the html5 (that was hard to me) but when I want to display it, I have to reload the page to see the info, because at first I see nothing! :(

Can someone help me please?
Thanks a lot!

p.s. I usually open it on firefox as safari and chrome do not open it. (I think because of my configuration)

```
var xml;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "base_es.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});
//loading XML file and parsing to .main div.
function xmlParser(data) {
    xml = data;
    $('#load').fadeOut();
    $(xml).find("fac").each(function () {
    name = $(this).attr("id");
    name2 = $(this).find("esc").text();
    var curso = $(this).find("curso").text();
    $("#list").append("<li><a href='hor3.html?id=" + name + "'data-transition='slide'><h3  id='name'>" + name + "</h3></a></li>");
    }); $('#list').listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: nothing in code shown would cause problem... are errors thrown in console ?

Comment: The problem comes when I go to that page from a previous one, for example that is the previous: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12291198/index.html and when I click noticias, I have to reload the data to see the news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have seen that I can reload the page with `location.reload();`  or with `top.location.href='hor2.html';`